# How to partially read from a TStringStream, free the read data from the stream and keep the rest (the unread data)?

Tags: string, delphi, stream, stringstream

What I want to do: lets suppose I have a TStringStream that just read a string with 100 characters. If I call .ReadString(50), I will get the first 50 characters of this stream and its cursor is going to be placed on the position 51.

My question is: how do I toss the characters 1 to 50 in this stream in a fast and clean way? I want to read the rest (51 to 100) later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to toss them? Just leave the position where it is and reading another 50 characters later will read characters 51 to 100 just fine.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I need to toss it because once something is read I don't need it anymore and this TStringStream object is persistent.

Comment: It is not correct to say that TStringStream is persistent, it's rather a string-storage-backed  in-memory stream, which is NOT persistent (not saved on the disk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you are hoping to do. The string stream's data is a Delphi string which is stored as a single memory block. Memory blocks are atomic, they cannot be split. You cannot free some part of a memory block.

If you really need to return memory to the memory manager then you should create a new string with the already processed data removed. You can then re-create your string stream with this new input and destroy the previous string stream.

Having said that, it's hard to see that doing much other than increasing your memory fragmentation. If the sizes of memory involved are large enough, and if the string stream persists for long enough, then this just might be a sensible approach. Otherwise it sounds like an attempt to optimise that actually would hinder performance.

Perhaps some class other than string stream could be more appropriate but it's very hard to advise without knowing more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. If you really need to do this, you should write your own class that implements the stream-interface and which would let you process some data a little bit at a time and free whatever you want to free. Note that you would only be able to go through the data once, since you've now deleted your data.  That is, seeking to the beginning again would become impossible, and your current stream "position" would be a lie.

In short, sounds like you're confused.

Comment: There are other ways to achieve what I am trying. It is not that confusing to use a stream in a producer/consumer context. :)

Comment: I disagree. It's a mis-use of a stream pattern.  A producer/consumer pattern could be implemented in lots of ways. A TStringList would be a better data structure than a stream for a Producer/Consumer/Queue. You could process a line and then delete it, freeing its memory.  :-)

Comment: @Warren, I disagree with the "fact" it's impossible ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you which to skip forward in the stream?

You can do:

```
  Str.Position := Str.Position + 50;
```

Or like this:

```
  Str.Seek(50,TSeekOrigin.soCurrent);
```

Comment: Can you do that in string streams? And what does Pos mean when you have 16 bit chars.

Comment: My question is: I want to free the memory that was read and keep the rest of the stream.

Comment: @haole If that really is your question, you need to ask that question. Please edit your question with the newly supplied constraint.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan title: "How to partially read from a TStringStream and toss the read data?". I specified TOSS in the title and also in the question's body. Don't know what else would need.

Comment: Except you are not asking to toss the data read from the string stream, you are asking to toss the data in the string stream.

Comment: @haole I don't think you can use a stringstream like that. If you want to rearrange the data you need to copy the strings you need to another stream, and then use LoadFromStream to replace the content in the first stream.